# Setting Parameters With SetValue is Giving me Errors, While Direct Member Referencing Works

Tags: c#, graphics, parameters, xna, effects

In XNA 4.0, using stand VS 2010 IDE...

The following line gives me an error.

```
    public EffectManager(ContentManager myContManager, GraphicsDevice myGFX)
    {
        defaultEffect = new BasicEffect(myGFX);
        //defaultEffect.Parameters["TextureEnabled"].SetValue(true);
        myContent = myContManager;
    }
```

However, if I change this to:

```
    public EffectManager(ContentManager myContManager, GraphicsDevice myGFX)
    {
        defaultEffect = new BasicEffect(myGFX);
        defaultEffect.TextureEnabled = true;
        myContent = myContManager;
    }
```

It works!  Why can't I set it using SetValue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those statements are not equivalent at all, use the second one.

The Parameters member of Effect provides a list of shader parameters for custom effects. I'm not sure you should ever be using Parameters on BasicEffect, the error may be because BasicEffect doesn't supply any parameters.

Also, if the second code block works, what's the problem?

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that... my issue was I had a function that sets parameters of pre-loaded FX... I will just modify the conditionals to access the correct parameters, thanks!